# ProgressDialog show too much late with Asynch task in Android

Tags: android

I am new in android. I am trying to display `ProgressDialog`  when click on button .

**This is my code:**

```
// set listener
btn_Login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //progress.show();

    MyAsynch    asynch = new MyAsynch();
    asynch.execute();
}
```

In this code progress dialog too much late appear when i am comment on Asynctask object then progress dialog appear normally.

I am puting my progress dialog in 
`AsynchTask` method

`onPreExecute()` but  same out put dialog display late .

How to solve my problem..??

I am also read stack answers following link but not solve my problem .

[async task progress dialog show too late](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495547/async-task-progress-dialog-show-too-late)

[ProgressDialog appears too late and dissapears too fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823365/progressdialog-appears-too-late-and-dissapears-too-fast)

here is my Asynctask code

```
        private class MyAsynch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog progress;
        String login_stat;
        String stat;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progress.setTitle(" User Login ");
            progress.setMessage("Please Wait!!");
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progress.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {

                login_stat = s_ApiHandling.doLogin(m_Et_Username.getText()
                        .toString().trim(), m_Et_Password.getText()
                        .toString().trim());


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("internet connection loss ");
                stat = "ERORR";
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return stat;
        }


   @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String status) {

                progress.dismiss();




            }

    }
```

Comment: post your MyAsynch code .

Comment: whats in your async task?

Comment: what are you doing man ,just write your progressbar code inside onPreExecute.

Comment: @KingCobraa i am put my asyntask code

Comment: @KingCobraa i  tried progress bar code inside onPreExecute but not solve .

Comment: see if you are not doing anything with progressbar in your asnytask .how it ll diplay before your sending data.

Comment: you want your progress dialog when you click on button, then you ll have to follow this rule ..onPreExecute ,doInBackground or if necessary onPostExecute

Comment: can you do one thing create one thread inside your activity and show your dialog on  onClick and inside the thread call your MyasynkTask with 2 sec sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing too much in `onPreExecute`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `progress.cancel()` from your `doInBackground` method and put it in to a `onPostExecute` method in your AsyncTask (like the second link you posted)

You shouldn't have anything talking to the UI in a background thread - that should all be done in pre/post execution.

Answer (score 0):

you code should look like this:

```
AsyncTask<String, Void, String>()
{
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        //ALL CODE GOES HERE.
    }
}
```

When you call the asynctask you must not use the `get()` method or the progress dialog won't work correctly.